# Library not loaded SDL2 using Xcode Version 13.3.1 on macOS 12.3.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, sdl-2

Am trying to learn `SDL2` using `Xcode Version 13.3.1` on `macOS Monterey 12.3.1`

Followed these steps:

1. Downloaded/ran the `dmg` file and moved the extracted `SDL2.framework` top-level folder into `/Library/Frameworks`
2. Inside Xcode, made `Command line` project, specifying C++ as the language.
3. Inside Xcode's General tab, I added `SDL2.framework` under `Frameworks and Libraries` and chose for `Embed` as `Do Not Embed`
4. Inside Xcode's Build Settings, under `Search Paths / Framework Search Paths` - I added the appropriate `${inherited}` and `${PROJECT_DIR}` (both set to `non-recursive`).

Now, when I try to `build` the project (even if I copy some introductory code, which is, for a small window rendering via an online tutorial), I get the following error:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x10005a0d4 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x10005a0d9 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10005a0dc <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10005a0de <+10>: jae    0x10005a0e8               ; <+20>
    0x10005a0e0 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10005a0e3 <+15>: jmp    0x100017150               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x10005a0e8 <+20>: retq   
    0x10005a0e9 <+21>: nop    
    0x10005a0ea <+22>: nop    
    0x10005a0eb <+23>: nop
```

---

```
dyld[22494]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/pnwlover/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello_sdl-buacbgrhmffapiexkmaxsewyxqvl/Build/Products/Debug/hello_sdl
  Reason: tried: '/Users/pnwlover/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello_sdl-buacbgrhmffapiexkmaxsewyxqvl/Build/Products/Debug/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (code signature in <AEE63968-5A4B-3298-93A8-8AB781F92E22> '/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' not valid for use in process: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs), '/System/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (no such file)
(lldb)
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Why was this question/post given a `-1` rating? I am only trying to learn by asking questions...

Comment: Can you try installing SDL2 with brew ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by making sure I embed and sign the SDL framework.

Answer (score 0):

XCode is completely useless for SDL, i recommend you use another IDE like Visual Studio Code

If you are gonna use VSCode, when you make a directory for your project add a `.vscode` folder, add `c_cpp_properties.json`, and then write the following code in there

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well done , you have successfully installed `SDL2.framework` ,it is a symbol representation of success when  i saw '/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 ```.

Now you should check steps like that:

1.`Project -> Build Phases -> New Copy File Phase` insert SDL2.framework as a `Share Frameworks` and don not mark `Copy only when installing`.

2.if you use `SDL2.framework` as static framework or dynamic framework,you have to use `Embed` with signed , because `SDL2.framework` is a command line client.

I hope i can help you to speed up of solving problem.

Sincerity!